# Apostrophe Widget Helper Not Waiting to Return

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've been working with widgets a lot in Apostrophe lately, and ran into a bit of a problem with helpers for widgets. I have a helper on my widget that checks some fields across different objects to determine whether or not it should show itself on the page. However, I've noticed a weird problem - it looks like whenever I try to load some modules the helper is not waiting for the async toArray method to finish before returning. So, when I have the code below:

```
    self.addHelpers({
        familyMembers: function() {
            var userId = "set from context";

            var userModule = self.apos.modules['apostrophe-users'].find(req, {_id: userId}).permission(false);

            userModule.toArray(function (err, arr) {
                var showMe = false;

                if (some_condition) {
                    showMe = true;
                }

                return showMe;
            })
        }
    })
```

It doesn't actually return anything to the template. But, when I return any value outside of the toArray and inside the top level of the function, it does return the value I set. Is there anyway around this? I was assuming that the method wasn't waiting for the toArray method to finish before returning, but I could be completely wrong on that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helpers are executed synchronously, your last chance to do async work is by providing a `pageBeforeSend` function.

http://apostrophecms.org/docs/technical-overviews/how-apostrophe-handles-requests.html#code-page-before-send-code-your-last-chance-to-do-async-work-for-a-page

Here is an example of it being extended using the `super` pattern https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe/blob/1c0b977470a81caec7a98146db4dbd46167f6ee4/lib/modules/apostrophe-pieces-pages/index.js#L387

Comment: The right answer, but perhaps not the best example, because in that example the `pageBeforeSend` method provided doesn't take a callback. Just to be clear, it can accept `(req, callback)` instead of just `(req)`, in which case your async code should end by invoking `callback(null)`.

(In general, if you don't see a callback as an argument to a function, there's no reason to expect it would wait for async code to run.)